# Handling multiple events from a service on a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Say I have the controller as follows:

```
public class Controller
{
    ISomeService _service;

    public Controller(ISomeService service)
    {
        _service = service;
        _service.EventFired += EventFired;
        _service.SomeEventFired += SomeOtherEventFired;
    }

    private void EventFire(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Might occur on FireSomeEvents();
        // Go to another controller
    }

    private void SomeOtherEventFired(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Might occur on FireSomeEvents();
        // Go to another view on this page
    }

    public void Create()
    {
        _service.FireSomeEvents();

        if(EventFired == true)
        {
            return View("EventFired");
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("SomeOtherEventFired");
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to handle the Redirect and View in a better way, because in the end I will end up with 3 potential events on my service.

I'm just wondering whether this is a design smell, or whether there is a better way to implement the redirect to pages...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events don't play nicely with ASP.NET MVC. Their model is not adapted to the MVC pattern. If you want to use them you may take a look at [asynchronous controllers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598.aspx).